# Me aparece: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

Estoy trabajando con react utilizando vite, y cuando compilo me aparece el siguiente error: (Esto no me aparece al hacer: npm run dev, pero si me aparece luego de usar npm run build y npm run preview). Por cierto estoy utilizando splidejs.

El código de index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="icon" as="image" type="image/png" href="/icon.png" />
    <link rel="preload" as="image" type="image/png" href="/assets/bg_iphone3.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/@splidejs/splide/dist/css/splide.min.css" type="text/css">
    <title>iPhone 15</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/@splidejs/splide/dist/js/splide.min.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="/src/js/all.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

El código de all.js: (Si pongo app.js antes de los otros archivos me sale: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getAttribute'))

```
import "./functions/locked"
import "./functions/buttonHome"
import "./functions/actions"
import "./functions/app"
```

El código de actions.js: (El error me aparece cuando quiere ejecutar: addEventListener('mousedown'), seria la linea 21)

```
let divFinder = document.createElement("div")
let imgFinder = document.createElement("img")
let buscar = document.createElement("span")

divFinder.id="finder"
imgFinder.src="/assets/iconsSystem/finder.png"
buscar.textContent="Buscar"
divFinder.appendChild(imgFinder)
divFinder.appendChild(buscar)


setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("loader").style.display="none"
}, 1000)

setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementsByClassName("splide__pagination__page").style.display="none"
    document.getElementsByClassName("splide__pagination").appendChild(divFinder)
}, 1000)

document.getElementsByClassName("splide__slide").addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
    console.log("jo")
    document.getElementById("finder").style.display="none" 
    document.getElementsByClassName("splide__pagination__page").style.display="block"
})
document.getElementsByClassName("splide__slide").addEventListener("mouseup",()=>{
    document.getElementById("finder").style.display="block"
    document.getElementsByClassName("splide__pagination__page").style.display="none" 
})
document.getElementsByClassName("splide__slide").addEventListener("mouseout", ()=>{
    document.getElementById("finder").style.display="block"
    document.getElementsByClassName("splide__pagination__page").style.display="none" 
})


if (document.getElementById("finder").getAttribute(display) === "block") {
    document.getElementsByClassName("splide__pagination__page").style.display="none" 
}else if(document.getElementById("finder").getAttribute(display) === "none"){
    document.getElementsByClassName("splide__pagination__page").style.display="block"
}
```

Estructura de carpetas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es fácil saber si el problema son las imágenes. Comenta esa línea y si el problema sigue es porque no era eso. Se me hace que el problema debe pasar por jQuery. Yo creo que no deberías usar jQuery con React, al menos no me parece una práctica frecuente.

Comment: No tenia planeado usar jquery, pero cuando comence a escribir en js me aprecia error, me parecio extraños, y por eso intente con jquery. Me fijo lo que comentaste y veo si se soluciona.

Comment: Pase mi codigo de jquery a  js vanilla, pero ahora al hacer "npm run dev" me aparece: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).addEventListener is not a function
    at actions.js:21:50.
  
En esta linea esta escrito lo siguiente:
document.getElementsByClassName("splide__slide").addEventListener('mousedown', function(){ ....})

Comment: Carga el código (y como texto). Por cierto, mira [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53507205/13419694).

Comment: Ya sé por qué es el error. `getElementsByClassName` devuelve una lista. Puedes iterarla y agregar el listener a cada elemento o hacer un `Array.from(lista).forEach(x => x.addEvent...)`

Comment: Aunque las imágenes sean útiles, insisto. Por favor pon el código como texto o ambos.

Comment: solucione el problema de esta pregunta con esto: window.onload = function () {...}. Sin embargo, ahora me tengo otro problema, y es que ciertos archivos de js no me los ejecuta. Por cierto, los otros archivos (son 4 en total)de los que me refiero les tuve que agregar el codigo  window,onload=function(){} y solo uno se me ejecuta.

Comment: Porque esa forma solo permite un solo listener, que es el último que asigna la variable `onload`. Mejor usa `window.addEventListener("load", ...)` que permite agregar varios

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera:
1.- Primero puse cada código de los 4 archivos dentro de:

```
window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{ ... }
```

2.- Luego capture los elementos con:

```
getElementsClassName(...)[0].
```

3.- Por ultimo accedí al hijo del elemento con:

```
let childs = splidePagination.childNodes
```

Todo el código del archivo actions.js quedaria asi:

```
window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("loader").style.display="none"
}, 1000)

let divFinder = document.createElement("div")
let imgFinder = document.createElement("img")
let buscar = document.createElement("span")
let splidePagination = document.getElementsByClassName("splide__pagination--ltr")[0]
let childs = splidePagination.childNodes

divFinder.id="finder"
imgFinder.src="/assets/iconsSystem/finder.png"
buscar.textContent="Buscar"
childs[0].style.display="none"
childs[1].style.display="none"

divFinder.appendChild(imgFinder)
divFinder.appendChild(buscar)

splidePagination.appendChild(divFinder)

let splide = document.getElementsByClassName("splide__list")[0]
splide.addEventListener("mouseup", ()=>{/*Presionar click*/
    divFinder.style.display="none"
    childs[0].style.display="block" 
    childs[1].style.display="block"
})
splide.addEventListener("mousedown", ()=>{/*Soltar click*/
    divFinder.style.display="none" 
    childs[0].style.display="block"
    childs[1].style.display="block"
})
splide.addEventListener("mouseover", ()=>{/*Ingresar al elemento*/
    divFinder.style.display="flex"
    childs[0].style.display="none"
    childs[1].style.display="none"
})
splide.addEventListener("mouseout", ()=>{/*Salir del elemento*/
    divFinder.style.display="flex" 
    childs[0].style.display="none"
    childs[1].style.display="none"
})
splide.addEventListener("click", ()=>{/*Ingresar al elemento*/
    divFinder.style.display="flex"
    childs[0].style.display="none"
    childs[1].style.display="none"
})

})
```